# Pymongo - Exclude a field from results in a raw query

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, mongoengine

According to [MongoEngine Docs on Raw Queries](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries), a raw query can be used in Python when getting a collection of objects like so:

```
Page.objects(__raw__={'tags': 'coding'})
```

What would be an example of using this method to exclude a particular field from the results?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `__raw__` for this, you have 2 options:

Using mongoengine, you need to use [exclude](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.exclude):

```
Page.objects(__raw__={'tags': 'coding'}).exclude('field1', 'field2')
```

Using pymongo (the underlying driver) - but then you won't be able to iterate over mongoengine `Page` instances but only over simple dict's (i.e pymongo's output):

```
page_collection = Page._get_collection()
query = page_collection.find({'tags': 'coding'}, {'field1': False, 'field2': False})
```